# material ui switch component not visible in windows 11 contrast themes

Tags: css, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui, windows-11

> Im working on a reactjs web app which has a material ui switch
> component and is visible in windows 10 OS, but when Windows 11 OS
> contrast theme like desert, aquatic, night sky,dusk are applied then
> the switch is not visible. How to make it visible in both Windows 10
> and 11 OS.

```
         import Switch from "@mui/material/Switch"; 

          <Grid item xs={4} sm={4} md={4} className="switchGrid">
            <Switch
              {...label}
              tabIndex={0}
              checked={JSON.parse(switchValue)}
              onChange={(e) => handleSwitchChange(e, "switchkey")}
                
            />
          </Grid>

   .switchGrid {
      .MuiSwitch-thumb {
        background-color: pink !important;
      }

      .MuiSwitch-track {
        background-color: red !important;
      }
    }
```